# Which `if(!isset($foo) OR (isset($foo) AND $foo == $bar))` or `if(!isset($foo) OR $foo == $bar)` is better?

Tags: php

I'm aware it's probably a "noob question", but I was wondering which one of those propositions I should use :

```
1. if(!isset($foo) OR (isset($foo) AND $foo == $bar)) {}
2. if(!isset($foo) OR $foo == $bar) {}
```

The thing is, I'm asking if the "OR" in the condition is naturally saying "`$foo` exists, you chan check his value if you want" or if you have to specifiy it could exists (with the `isset` thing).

Thank you for your answers, and sorry for my appromixative english.... :)

Comment: The first one is redundant, so use #2.

Comment: Which one is better. The one where you don't duplicate the condition for no good reason or the one where you duplicate the condition for no good reason?

Comment: @Ryan Thx ! So as I thought, the `or` in the condition is enough to say the variable $foo exists.

@PeeHaa , can I have more explications ? Why are saying there's no good reason ? In my if condition, I have to check if a variable does not exists or, if it does, it's equal to a specific value... How would you have done that ?

Comment: `OR` performs short-circuiting. So the second expression is only evaluated if the first one is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OR`, `AND`, `||`, and `&&` all perform [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). `OR` and `||` evaluate their arguments left-to-right until they get to the first truthy value, and then return that. `AND` and `&&` evaluate their arguments left-to-right until they get to the first falsy value, and return it. In both cases, they don't evaluate any of the remaining arguments.

So you should use #2, because when `!isset($foo)` is true it will never evaluate the second expression, so there's no need to check `isset($foo)` again.